# After upgrade 2019.2.3 to 2019.3, running kotlin in Intellij Debugger gets stuck in Collection data

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a `test.kts` to show the issue I have:

```
fun solution(A: IntArray): Int {
    if (A.distinct().size != A.size) {
        return 0
    }
    val expected = (A.size.toDouble()) * (A.size.toDouble() + 1) / 2
    val real = A.map { it.toDouble() }.sum()

    return if (expected == real) 1 else 0
}


check(0 == solution(listOf(1, 4, 1).toIntArray()))
```

In Debugger mode, there is a break point at `return if (expected == real) 1 else 0`

If wanted to check `A`, it shows `collecting data` forever.
Same when I want to evaluate `expected == real`

Basically what I saw is as the following picture

[image]

Based on what I found on internet, I have tried:

- disable and enable kotlin plugin
- invalidate cache and restart
- remove `.idea` and open the project
- rebuild project
- restart computer
- disable all plugins and enable again

None of them work. When using java project, the debugger works fine.

Versions:

- intellij: 2019.3
- java: 11.0.5.hs-adpt
- kotlin: 1.3.60-release-IJ2019.3-1